# A question in combinatorics of cards, using the number of integer solutions to the equation $r_1+\dots+r_k=n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

It is known that the number of non-negative integer solutions to the equation $r_1+\dots+r_k=n$ is $\begin{pmatrix} {n+k-1}\\{k-1}\end{pmatrix}$ and the number of positive integer solutions is $\begin{pmatrix} {n-1}\\{k-1}\end{pmatrix}$.

I am asked to use this in order to calculate the probability that in a randomly shuffled deck of cards there are no two aces right after the other.

I tried thinking what this equation can represent in our case, but got nowhere.
A hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a deck with 4 $A$s and 48 $*$s. 
You want to count the number of arrangements like those below, where the remaining 45 $*$s are distributed over the five blank spaces. 
$$\underline{\hphantom{aaa}} A*\underline{\hphantom{aaa}}A*\underline{\hphantom{aaa}}A*\underline{\hphantom{aaa}}A\underline{\hphantom{aaa}} $$

There are as many of these as solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=45$ in non-negative integers.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! So now, the ways of organizing the deck will be of 4 identical objects and 48 other identical objects, no meaning to their identity. So the number of ways is 52 choose 4, and the number of ways of organizing without two Aces coming one after the other is 49 choose 4, so the probability is, and simplification, $\frac{46 \cdot 47 \cdot 48} {50 \cdot 51\cdot 52}$. Seems correct?

Comment: @Whyka Yes, you are correct.